# Regex replace +46 to 0 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to learn regex. I need to find +46 and replace it with 0. I've been racking my brain but I can't figure out the correct syntax. I'm trying to do it in JS with replace.

Any takers?

Comment: Post your code here, so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: What does your regex look like so far?

Comment: I don't have anything usable. I can't understand how to find and replace! replace.(/[+46], ''/, $string); or something to that effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.replace()`:

```
"987654321+46".replace("+46", "0")
```